# Как сделать фон с полосками по диагонали?

Tags: html, css, css3

Как сделать фон с полосками по диагонали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну например `background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Qdd.png);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div.striped {
      background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        #333333,
        #333333 25px,
        #000000 25px,
        #000000 50px
      );
    }
```

```html
<div class="striped" style="height: 200px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

very simply

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #000000 25%, #333333 25%, #333333 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 75%, #333333 75%, #333333);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

and more

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #555 25%, #222 25%, #222 50%, #555 50%, #555 75%, #222 75%, #000);
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

3d

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #555 25%, #555 25%, #222 50%, #555 50%, #555 75%, #222 75%, #000);
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

cool?